# how to download back my pictures, in case I lose my phone

Tags: onedrive

I'm using a nokia Xl and i have saved quiet a lot of pictures on my onedrive app.i fear is, can i download back the pictures if am to lose the phone

Answer (score 3):

Once you've got the photos backed up to OneDrive you should not lose the pictures (assuming you don't forget your Microsoft Account details).

All your files on OneDrive (including those uploaded from your computer or tablet) are available within the OneDrive app, and you can choose to download them back to your new phone if you so desire.

Comment: "Should not".... Yeah I agree. Unfortunately OneDrive has twice now decided it would randomly delete some pictures for me. (I've now moved to DropBox.)